# Dim the screen using software instead of hardware in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, brightness

I have a Thinkpad P52 which has the issue of PWM flickering if the brightness is lowered using the hardware keys. I've tried installing [Desktop Dimmer](https://github.com/sidneys/desktop-dimmer) both via source and the deb package but it fails.

Are there other softwares which can just as easily help me reduce the brightness of the screen using software?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried brightnessctl?

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/brightnessctl.1.html

Comment: I believe it is still hardware-based instead of being software-based?